# How to multiply elements of a list of vectors by elements of arrays one by one (matches element)

Tags: r

## The idea:

Suppose I have a list of `10` vectors and would like to multiply each vectors by specific values of the arrays by columns. That is, the first vectors values multiplied only by the first element of each array. Then, the second vector values multiplied only by the second element of each array. Do that for all vectors. Since I have `10` vectors (each with `100` values) and `100` arrays, each have `10` non-zero values. Then, I would like to do one by one multiplication as described above.

## Example,

1. **Take the first vector of the list. `x[[1]]` then multiply each element of it by each first element of the arrays**.
2. **Then the second vectors values multiplied by each second element of the arrays**.
3. **Then, the third vectors values multiplied by each third element of the arrays**.
4. Do that for all other vectors.

## Numerical example:

Suppose I have a list of vector and the following vectors are the first and second vector of my list.

```
[[1]]
 [1] 2.174090 1.666464 1.915763 2.282967 2.407327 1.386437 2.854528 1.896338 2.010713 1.013387 .......... (`100` values)

[[2]]
 [1]  2.3020147  3.3311029 -0.3103701  3.2445878  5.6261224  5.2914477 -1.0621042  3.0790536  3.6186598
[10]  4.1846937 ........ (`100` values)

[[3]]
 [1]  0.42808525  4.02348551 -2.31160703  5.56077594  2.83856320 -0.02850242  1.57480238 -2.68603276
 [9]  2.34598854  4.14115289 ....(`100` values)
```

Suppose I have a list of arrays (`100`) arrays which contains `10` values. and let's the following arrays are the first and second arrays of my array list.

```
, , 1

           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[2,] -0.4610817  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[3,]  0.4697426 -0.07296078  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[4,] -0.2790043 -0.77459992 -0.7478920  0.000000    0
[5,] -0.2156273 -2.59804286 -0.9390597 -1.746925    0

    , , 2

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[2,] -0.21896586  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[3,] -0.09066381  0.2920374  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[4,]  1.27289131 -0.2748794  1.0862465  0.000000    0
[5,] -1.20050567 -1.0934879 -0.7707806 -2.180104    0
```

Then I would like to multiply the first element of the first vector by the first non-zero values of the array. That is, `2.174090 * -0.4610817` . **Then, the second element of the first vector will multiplied by the first element of the second array** i.e., `1.666464 * -0.21896586` . Then, **the first element of the second vector multiplied by the second element of the first array**, i.e., `2.3020147 * 0.4697426` **and the second element of the second vector by the second element of the second array** i.e., `3.3311029 *  -0.09066381` .

The third vectors multiplied by each third elements of the arrays.

`0.42808525 *  -0.2790043`

That is:

**The element of the first vector multiplied only by the first element of the arrays (one by one). Then, then the second vector multiplied only by the second element of the arrays**.

## Code:

```
 a <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 100), c(5, 5, 100))
 for(k in seq(dim(a)[3])) a[,,k][upper.tri(a[,,k], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
 a



 x <- rnorm(100,2,2)
 
  x <- rep(list(x), 10)
```

I tried the answer (Thanks so much) but got error: (`x` is a list`)

```
 > a[a!=0] <- a[a!=0]*x
Error in a[a != 0] * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any idea, please?

Comment: @akrun Thanks, No this is quite different. That multiplies each vectors by each arrays. Here each element by each element.

Comment: BTW, you showed a vector 'x'.  Do you have a `list` of vectors or not?

Comment: Yes. I have a list of vector.

Comment: all the element of the first vectors only multiplied by the first element of each array one by one. all the element of the second vectors multiplied by the second element of all arrays and so on.

Comment: Try `a[a!=0] <- a[a!=0]*x`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. I will try it and see.

Comment: Do you have a single array or a list of arrays.  Now the `dim(a)#
[1]   5   5 100`

Comment: I have `100` arrays.

Comment: Please check your example.  Your 'a' is a single 3 D array.  If you meant, the the third dimenion length is 100, then it is correct

Comment: yes, I meant the length of the third dimension is 100.

Comment: Okay, in that case, the updated answer should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do an assignment based on the non-zero values.  As the `vector` 'x' is having the same length as the number of non-zero values in each slice of 2D array, we can make use of the recycling of 'x'

```
a[a!=0] <- a[a!=0]*x 
dim(a)
#[1]  5  5 10
```

---

The values before the assignment

```
a[2,1,1]*x[1]
#[1] 1.462893
a[2,1,2]*x[1]
#[1] -0.2332104
```

after the assignment

```
a[2, 1, 1]
#[1] 1.462893
a[2, 1, 2]
#[1] -0.2332104
```

---

If we need to multiply by a `list` ('x'), then `unlist` it and create a `matrix` `byrow=TRUE` to get the elements multiplied correctly

```
a[a != 0] <- a[a != 0]*do.call(rbind, x)
```

The values before the assignment

```
a[2,1,1]*x[[1]][1]
#[1] 0.2297043

a[3,1,1]*x[[2]][1]
#[1] 0.1796345
```

Values after the assignment

```
a[2, 1, 1]
#[1] 0.2297043
a[3, 1, 1]
#[1] 0.1796345
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
a <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 10), c(5, 5, 10))
for(k in seq(dim(a)[3])) a[,,k][upper.tri(a[,,k], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank so much. However, It gave me a vector. I would like to save then in arrays.

Comment: @Alice Have you done any changes?  With the example, I am getting an array as output i.e. `a[a!=0] <- a[a!=0]*x`

Comment: No. I did not. I will do it again.

Comment: Hi. First of all thank for all your great and interesting help. I really appreciated all that. yesterday, I thought the answer is what I really want (so, sorry). Then, I found that it is not exactly what I want. I saw that you only multiply one vector of the list. Is that correct? I updated my question. I really would like to accept your answer since your work always great. Would you like to look at my question again. Your answer is very close. but It gave me an error for the list of vector.

Comment: @Alice Earlier because it was not assigned to 'x'.  So, i thought it is just a single vector

Comment: Yes. I thought that.

Comment: @Alice Do you want  `a[a!=0] <- a[a!=0]*unlist(x)`

Comment: `a[2,1,1]*x[[1]][1]`, this means the first element of the second row of the first arrays multiplied by the first element of the first vector of `x`

Comment: No. I need them as list.

Comment: @Alice  You are updating the array right.  So, in that case, the output will be an array

Comment: Yes, I want it to be arrays. `10` arrays in my case because I will then sum them.

Comment: When you assign the output, it will be array

Comment: The main idea is how to multiply the first elements of the first vector only by the first elements of each array. The second with the second elements and so on.

Comment: That is, I would like to multiply each element of the first vector by only the first elements of each arrays. one by one. since I have `10` elements in the first vectors, they will be multiplied (one by one) by the first element of each arrays `10` arrays = `10` first elements.

Comment: @Alice Updated the post.  Please check

Comment: Sorry, I am thinking that, if we can do this `a[i, j, k]` then multiplied it by the element of the vectors. by I do not know how to do it with the vectors.

Comment: @Alice I am getting the output you mentioned by multiplying

Comment: I am trying it. my orginal function is so complicated and need a time. I will response you soon. Thanks so much for your kind and great help.

Comment: @Alice Here, I am assuming that the length of `x` vectors are the same i.e. 10 and is the same as the number of non-zero elements in each array elements.

Comment: @Alice Could you also clarify the elements to be multiplied for `a[2,1,2]` and `a[3, 1, 2]`

Comment: Yes, it is true. Each vector has `10` elements`. each element of the first vectors multiplied by each first element by each vector. So, the first element by the first element of the first array. The second element of the first vector by the first element of the second array and so on.

Comment: I will update the question. But I think what you did is correct.

Comment: @Alice I just wanted to make sure whether it is right or not

Comment: for the example I provide it is correct. but I am waiting my function. I am really so sorry.

Comment: @Alice It is okay.  You can test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158468/discussion-between-akrun-and-alice).

Comment: @Alice Try `a[a != 0] <- a[a != 0]*do.call(rbind, x)`