# How to multiply a vector by function output element by element in R

Tags: arrays, r

This question is relative to my question here: [My old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152440/how-to-multiply-elements-of-a-list-of-vectors-by-elements-of-arrays-one-by-one)

However, In this question, I would like to multiply a vector element by the function output.

**Here is a description of my question:**

## The idea

Suppose I have a list of `10` vectors and would like to multiply each vectors by specific values of the arrays by columns. That is, the first vectors values multiplied only by the first element of each array. Then, the second vector values multiplied only by the second element of each array. Do that for all vectors. Since I have `10` vectors (each with `100` values) and `100` arrays, each have `10` non-zero values. Then, I would like to do one by one multiplication as described above.

## Example

1. Take the first vector of the list. `x[[1]]` then multiply each element of it by each first element of the arrays.
2. Then the second vectors values multiplied by each second element of the arrays.
3. Then, the third vectors values multiplied by each third element of the arrays.
4. Do that for all other vectors.

## Numerical Example

Suppose I have a list of vector and the following vectors are the first and second vector of my list.

```
[[1]]
 [1] 2.174090 1.666464 1.915763 2.282967 2.407327 1.386437 2.854528 1.896338 2.010713 1.013387 .......... (`100` values)

[[2]]
 [1]  2.3020147  3.3311029 -0.3103701  3.2445878  5.6261224  5.2914477 -1.0621042  3.0790536  3.6186598
[10]  4.1846937 ........ (`100` values)

[[3]]
 [1]  0.42808525  4.02348551 -2.31160703  5.56077594  2.83856320 -0.02850242  1.57480238 -2.68603276
 [9]  2.34598854  4.14115289 ....(`100` values)
```

Suppose I have a list of arrays (`100`) arrays which contains `10` values. and let's the following arrays are the first and second arrays of my array list.

```
, , 1

           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[2,] -0.4610817  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[3,]  0.4697426 -0.07296078  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[4,] -0.2790043 -0.77459992 -0.7478920  0.000000    0
[5,] -0.2156273 -2.59804286 -0.9390597 -1.746925    0

    , , 2

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[2,] -0.21896586  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[3,] -0.09066381  0.2920374  0.0000000  0.000000    0
[4,]  1.27289131 -0.2748794  1.0862465  0.000000    0
[5,] -1.20050567 -1.0934879 -0.7707806 -2.180104    0
```

Then I would like to multiply the first element of the first vector by the first non-zero values of the array. That is, `2.174090 * -0.4610817`. **Then, the second element of the first vector will multiplied by the first element of the second array** i.e., `1.666464 * -0.21896586`. Then, **the first element of the second vector multiplied by the second element of the first array**, i.e., `2.3020147 * 0.4697426` **and the second element of the second vector by the second element of the second array** i.e., `3.3311029 *  -0.09066381`.

The third vectors multiplied by each third elements of the arrays.

`0.42808525 *  -0.2790043`

That is:

**The element of the first vector multiplied only by the first element of the arrays (one by one). Then, then the second vector multiplied only by the second element of the arrays**.

## Code:

```
set.seed(24)
myfun <- function(n, N){
  a <- array(rnorm(n * n * N), c(n, n, N))
  for(k in seq(dim(a)[3])) a[,,k][upper.tri(a[,,k], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
  out <- list()
  out$a <- a
  return(out)
}
```

I would like the code to be almost only one line. That because I have a complex function where the output is similar in the shape to my function output.

```
res <- sum(x* myfun(5,10)$a)
```

I tried this:

```
x <- rnorm(10,2,2)

x <- rep(list(x), 10)

res <- myfun(5,10)$a
res[res != 0] <- res[res != 0]*x[[1]]
```

However, it does not work as expected and I also would like to make the code work for the list not only `x[[1]]`.

That is, I would like to multiply and then take the sum to get a single value.

Comment: I am not sure why a one-liner is a requirement. Clarity can be good, and if your code becomes too long, split it in individual functions. Also, multiplying matrices element-wise is a default feature in R, so it should be simpler if you reshape your two datasets to the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, a few lines of code can help clarity rather than obscure one-liners.

For your problem though, you can take advantage of the fact that R makes vectorized computations, that is, element-wise for each element of your tables.

So I would first reshape the data. Your example data is something like this, correct me if I'm wrong:

- an array of dimension (n, n, N), which you described as a "list" of N arrays with n×n values, where the upper triangle is zero: they contain `p = n(n-1)/2` non-zero values;
- a list of `p` vectors of length N

#### Input data:

```
N <- 10
n <- 3
p <- n*(n-1)/2  # = 3

veclist <- list(
  c(2.174090, 1.666464, 1.915763, 2.282967, 2.407327, 1.386437, 2.854528, 1.896338, 2.010713, 1.013387),
  c(2.3020147, 3.3311029, -0.3103701, 3.2445878, 5.6261224, 5.2914477, -1.0621042, 3.0790536, 3.6186598, 4.1846937),
  c(0.42808525, 4.02348551, -2.31160703, 5.56077594, 2.83856320, -0.02850242, 1.57480238, -2.68603276, 2.34598854, 4.14115289)
)

arr <- myfun(n, N)$a
```

#### reshape:

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(veclist), nrow=length(veclist), byrow=T)
dim(mat) # 3 10

# reformat the lower triangle data of arrays
flatarr <- sapply(1:N, function(i) arr[,,i][lower.tri(arr[,,i])])
dim(flatarr) # 3 10
```

#### do the element-wise multiplication:

```
res <- mat * flatarr
```

So really it was just a matter of reshaping.

## Explanation

the `sapply` line above applies the same function to each of the 10 arrays. This function is:

```
function(i) {
    # take the array number `i`
    ai <- arr[,,i]
    # get the lower triangle values
    ai[lower.tri(ai)]
}
```

The output of sapply is automatically simplified to a matrix of dimension (3, 10), that is 3 lines and 10 columns.

## Caution while flattening the array:

R takes matrix elements **by columns**. If the order you want is by line, you must transpose the array and take the `upper.tri`, so the sapply function is the following:

```
function(i) t(arr[,,i])[upper.tri(t(arr[,,i]))]
```

## One-liner

(Once you defined `veclist` and `arr <- myfun(n,N)$a`)

```
res <- matrix(unlist(veclist), nrow=length(veclist), byrow=T) * sapply(1:N, function(i) arr[,,i][lower.tri(arr[,,i])])
```